# Zend create decorator for all form elemets

Tags: php, zend-framework

For one elment decorating I use

```
$this->getElement('usr_name')->addDecorator('Label', array('class' => 'control-label'));
```

maybe are faster solution to decorate `ALL` form `labels` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After elements have been added to the form use `setElementDecorators` to specify decorators for them.

Exampe:

```
class Form_Example extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* creating form elements*/



        // specify all element decorators    
        $this->setElementDecorators(array(
            'ViewHelper',
            array('Label', array('class' => 'control-label')),
        ));

        // specify all form decorators
        $this->setDecorators(array(
            'FormElements',
            'Form'
        ));
    }
}
```

**However**, if you are trying to integrate `Zend_Form` and Twitter Bootstrap, there are already implemented solutions like: [EasyBib_Form_Decorator](https://github.com/easybib/EasyBib_Form_Decorator)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a function to add the decorator to all elements of the form

if `$form` is the form object. Implement a function which will loop through the input elements of `$form` object and add  decorator on each element

```
function addLabelDecorator($form)
{
    $formElements = $form->getElements();
    foreach($formElements as $element)
        $element->addDecorator('Label', array('class' => 'control-label'));

    return $form;   
}
```